# Function return empty then show echo no videos

Tags: php, function

so i have this code which is fetching videos from database , all working good , but when the result is empty it shows error (like if there are no videos that are matching with movie name then it shows `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` ) what im trying to do is if there is no videos matching with movie name then show echo no videos. my code:

```
function fetchvideo($mtitle=NULL)
{
    if($mtitle!=NULL) {
        $column = "moviename";
        $data = $mtitle;
    }
    global $mysqli; 
    $video= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vid,image,title,moviename FROM movie_videos WHERE $column = ?");
    $video->bind_param('s', $data);
    $video->execute();
    $video->bind_result($vid,$vimage,$vtitle,$moviename);
    while ($video->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('vid' => $vid, 'image' => $vimage, 'title' => $vtitle, 'moviename' => $moviename);
    }
    $video->close();
    return ($row);
}
```

Comment: Because it cannot loop trough something that is empty. The output can be null/false/0 or maybe more 'negative' values. In my opionion it is better to do: `if count($array) == 0` do something

Comment: yup i know , but is there nay way to show `no results` if the the result from database is empty because its showing error if there is no matching rows , else its working good

Comment: I'm not so good with mysqli/pdo but there must be a count function.if you do a count on the results you get back. You can give a custom error message back like : 'No videos found'

Comment: in function or where im using foreach() ?

Comment: see plenka's answer @user3499463

Comment: Thanks for pointing to my answer, JochemQuery. Which is quite a weird coincidence, as my youngest son is also called Jochem. It's his birthday today, he turned 4. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that throws the error is not shown, as no `foreach` is shown. However, it is easily solved by adding a single line to the above function:

```
function fetchvideo($mtitle=NULL)
{
    if($mtitle!=NULL) {
        $column = "moviename";
        $data = $mtitle;
    }
    global $mysqli; 
    $video= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vid,image,title,moviename FROM movie_videos WHERE $column = ?");
    $video->bind_param('s', $data);
    $video->execute();
    $video->bind_result($vid,$vimage,$vtitle,$moviename);

    $row = array();

    while ($video->fetch()){
        $row[] = array('vid' => $vid, 'image' => $vimage, 'title' => $vtitle, 'moviename' => $moviename);
    }
    $video->close();
    return ($row);
}
```

By adding a declaration of `$row` you make sure that an array is always returned, be it empty when no videos were found. You can then check before the foreach loop is executed whether videos are present and show the appropriate message if no videos are available:

```
if (!empty($row)) {
    foreach ($row as $video) {
        // Show video
    }
} else {
    echo 'No videos';
}
```